# Spring boot auto import utf-8 data from data.sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, utf-8, h2

I am trying to auto import some default data in `spring-boot`. I have created `data.sql` in resources folder with two insert statements, they have data in `utf-8`format. Also I checked the file in `Notepad++` encoding is correct.
This is how my data looks like,

> INSERT INTO SERVICE_REQUEST(id, name, address, amount, status) VALUES
>   (1, 'श्रीकांत हावळे', 'खडकी, पुणे', 1000, 'प्रलंबित');

I am using In-memory H2 database. And I am visualizing this data in table from `JavaFx`. Now interesting part is all works well, I am able to see the data correctly in table when I run the application via `IntelliJ`.

But if I build same application using `maven` into a `jar`. The data that shows up in `JavaFx` table gets messed up and is not shown properly. Instead of proper `utf-8` `devnagri` characters some weird symbols are shown.

So my understanding is,

1. In `Jar` file may be `data.sql` is not in `utf-8` encoding. But I did check it is in correct encoding.
2. Second I am thinking may be `spring-boot` is not reading the file properly, but then why it works in when I simply run application via `IntelliJ`
3. May be creating a `Jar` is then creating a problem.

As a work around I could listen to `ApplicationReadyEvent` and then import the needed data by `java` logic. But I would like to make this work using `data.sql`

Please provide your inputs or valuable suggestions.

Comment: Try to add this dependency `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>` into your `pom.xml` to set default encoding. BTW, please also check the preference in 'IntelliJ' for the preference of default encoding.

Comment: thank you for input, I did check both of your points and they indeed are present. So I am still not sure whats going wrong.